# Yii2 gridview search is not working

Tags: gridview, yii2

In my yii2 project gridview search is not working:
[image]

As in the picture if I manually add searchModel like this:

`<?php echo $this->render('_search', ['model' => $searchModel]); ?>`
it''s working (look at the upper part of the image). But gridview serachModel is not (look at the below). Where should I check for possible errors, which files?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've read many posts and noticed that this error may be caused by conflict included js files. In my yii2 project (in AppAsset.php) I firstly commented all js files and then gridview serch worked fine. Then I checked that which js file is conflicting by uncommenting one by one. Finally I found this file and modified as I need. So this worked for me. Via this question, at least, other programmers may know where they can look for error according this issue.

Comment: Yes, you are right @Sherzod, it's deu to **js conflict**.

Answer (score 0):

You need to check your controller. When you press **Search** button, request goes to some route (check what address you have in address bar after search) and find action which is used to do searching. [Debug](https://xdebug.org/docs/) values you have in that action.

For example, you can generate a new CRUD by means of [`gii`](http://www.yiiframework.com/doc-2.0/guide-start-gii.html) and find out how it works, than update your controller similarly.

Comment: This is address bar after clicking search button: `http://localhost/farmas/index.php?r=sf%2Findex&SfModelSearch%5Bid%5D=2&SfModelSearch%5Bsfraqam%5D=&SfModelSearch%5By_id%5D=&SfModelSearch%5Bsana%5D=`. What should I do now??

Comment: Find `actionIndex` in `SfController` and look what values do you have in  `SfModelSearch` by `Yii::$app->request->get('SfModelSearch')`

Comment: Take a look at this tutorial to figure out what's going on in your controller [Creating a Simple CRUD App With Yii2](http://www.yiiframework.com/wiki/490/creating-a-simple-crud-app-with-yii2-revised-12-20-2013/#hh9)

Comment: I've commented everything inside `actionIndex` and added this: `echo Yii::$app->request->get('SfModelSearch');`

Comment: I've commented everything inside `actionIndex` and added this: `echo Yii::$app->request->get('SfModelSearch');`. But nothing comes out. However, if I get model like this: `$all = SfModelSearch::find()->all()` then $all got all rows in database. So what should I do then?

Comment: Extra information: If I create new CRUD it is still not working. But, when I create new yii2 project then gridview search is working

Comment: `Yii::$app->request->get('SfModelSearch')` returns an array. You can use [`var_dump()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.var-dump.php) to see it's content

Comment: I tried like this: `var_dump(Yii::$app->request->get('SfModelSearch'))` and it's returning **NULL** value. Then what???

Comment: Add listing of your controller. WIthout code it's like guessing game